# Get variable within function and assign it to another variable out of its scope

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chartist.js

I am using Chartist and VueJS and I am trying to access data within my chart. When I click my chart, I should be able to get the information about the index of my click. I get this data, but I am having trouble passing that data to Vue itself.

Here is my current code:

```
  data() {
    return {
      monthIndex: 0,
      chartData: {
        labels: [],
        series: [[], []]
      },

      /* other chart options that I omitted */

      chartEventHandlers: [
        {
          event: "draw",
          fn(data) {
            if (data.type === "bar") {
              data.element.animate({
                y2: {
                  begin: data.index * 40,
                  dur: "0.3s",
                  from: data.y1,
                  to: data.y2,
                  easing: "easeOutQuad"
                },
                opacity: {
                  begin: data.index * 40,
                  dur: "0.3",
                  from: 0,
                  to: 1,
                  easing: "easeOutQuad"
                }
              });

              data.element._node.onclick = evt => {
                console.log(data.axisX.ticks[data.index]);
               // How do I assign this to monthIndex??

              };
              //
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    };
  }
```

As you can see here:

```
data.element._node.onclick = evt => {
                console.log(data.axisX.ticks[data.index]);
              };
```

I can get it to display the correct value in the console, I just am trying to figure out a way to make

```
monthIndex = data.axisX.ticks[data.index]
```

However, monthIndex does not exist in the scope of the function, so I can't simply assign it to that variable. How do I go about doing this? I am trying to get monthIndex to show up on the html View so that it changes everytime I click on another part of the chart.

Comment: bind vue scope to fn and you should be able to assign it with this.monthIndex = ...

Comment: Could you lead me or give me an example on how to accomplish this? Not very experienced with Vue

Comment: probably something like this `fn: function(data) { ... this.monthIndex = ... }.bind(this)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What [@Chris Li is saying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58085154/get-variable-within-function-and-assign-it-to-another-variable-out-of-its-scope#comment102564765_58085154) is that you can bind the Vue scope to a function by doing this:

```
function(data) {

}.bind(this)
```

Which allows you to access the Vue scope, or `this` inside of the function so to be able to assign the index value to the appropriate variable.